# Error Message after running npm install and ng new on an Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, jasmine, git-bash

i got some issues since Tuesday. I'm learning angular atm and create many projects a day :D
But as I said, since Tuesday I can neither do an **ng new**  nor an **npm install** - let alone a **ng serve**.

I'm adding a few pictures of the error messages!
Thanks in the front for your guys help :-)

Have a nice one tho.

This is the **ng new error message**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvmSx.png)

And This is the **npm install error message**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2llT.png)

ps: i've changed the jasmine version in the package.json, updated the angular/cli and npm! From here on I unfortunately don't know what to do next

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json`, try changing `jasmine-core` from `~3.6.0` to `^3.7.1` and then do a fresh `npm install`. It seems `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` requires a newer version of that package.

Comment: Hey AliF50, thank you for your answer. I’ve already changed the jasmine-core package in the package.json to the 3.7.1. After changing it if run npm install again - but always the same error message :-(

Comment: That is strange, I imagine that should have fixed it. Try deleting `node_modules` folder, deleting `package-lock.json` file and then run `npm install` again.